# Creating different dataframe and outputting it to different csv based on list of indexes

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a list of indexes like below based on N value. Here is the code I used to create the list of indexes

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(100).reshape((-1, 5)))
N = 4
ix = [[i, i+N] for i in range(0,len(df),N)]
ix
# [[0, 4], [4, 8], [8, 12], [12, 16], [16, 20]]
```

I want to create function which creates:

1) N dataframes (df_1, df_2, df_3, df_4, df_5). The rows in each dataframes is based on each list of indexes. For example, "df_1" will have all the rows between index 0 and 4 from the main dataframe df and similarly df_2 will have all the rows between index 4 and 8 from dataframe df

2) outputs each dataframes to csv as df_1.csv, df_2.csv ....

Below is the code I tried but "df_i = df.ix[i]" step only gets the row in the list not the range in the list :

```
def write(df, ix):
    for i in ix:
        try:
            df_i = df.ix[i]
            df_i.to_csv("a.csv", index = false)
        except:
            pass
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `iloc`

```
def write(df, ix):
    c = 1
    for i in ix:
        try:
            df_i = df.iloc[i[0]:i[1]] # use iloc
            df_i.to_csv(f"df_{str(c)}.csv", index=False) # f-strings to name file
            c+=1 # update your counter
        except:
            pass

df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(100).reshape((-1, 5)))
N = 5
ix = [(i, i+N) for i in range(0,len(df),N)]

write(df, ix)
```